# Java assign implemented class to generic interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am trying to achieve assigning a class that implements a generic typed interface. It's doable in C# with out keyword per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx:

```
interface ICovariant<out R>
{
    R GetSomething();
}
class SampleImplementation<R> : ICovariant<R>
{
    public R GetSomething()
    {
        // Some code. 
        return default(R);
    }
}

// The interface is covariant.
ICovariant<Button> ibutton = new SampleImplementation<Button>();
ICovariant<Object> iobj = ibutton;

// The class is invariant.
SampleImplementation<Button> button = new SampleImplementation<Button>();
```

But when I tried to achieved the same in Java, it failed:

```
interface IShape<T>
{
    T GetArea();
}

class Rectangle implements IShape<Number>
{
    public Number GetArea() {
        Double d = new Double(1.03);
        return d;
    }
}

class Test {
    void Try() {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        IShape<Object> s0 = r;//assignment failed
    }
}
```

The error is -> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Rectangle to IShape from Java 8's compiler. How can I achieve assigning a class that implements IShape to a reference of interface IShape< T>?

Comment: You can't do that. An `IShape<Number>` is not a subtype of `IShape<Object>`.

Comment: Try `IShape<?> s0 = r;`

Comment: Number is not the same as Object. if you adjust your interface's generic type to T extends Object instead of T, then i think it should work

Comment: Either `IShape<? extends Number> s0 = r;` OR `IShape<?> s0 = r;` would compile

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

```
class Rectangle implements IShape<Number>
```

With this:

```
class Rectangle<T extends Number> implements IShape<T>
```